# Getting an error: cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I recently added authentication to my website using `bcrypt`. When authenticating, `bcrypt` compares the passwords.

If passwords match `req.session` is set as a cookie and written to `mongodb` using `connect-mongodb-session`. But when redirecting to `/events` the app crashes and gives me an error: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

I'm using handlebars to render my html code

auth route:

```
Router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).render('login', {pageTitle: 'Log In'});
})

Router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  //Authenticate user
  const username = req.body.username;
  const pass = req.body.password;

  User.findOne({username: username}).then((user) => {
    if (user) {
      //Validate password
      console.log(user);
      console.log(user.password);
      bcrypt.compare(pass, user.password).then((doMatch) => {
        console.log(doMatch);
        //Check if password match
        if (doMatch) {
          //To use session use express-session package
          req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
          req.session.user = user;
          req.session.save((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/');
          });
          return res.redirect('/events');
        } else {
          res.redirect('/');
        }
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    } else {
      return res.redirect('/');
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

});
```

events route:

```
Router.get('/events', (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.isLoggedIn) {

  Event.find({}, (err, events) => {
    res.render('events', {
      prods: events,
      pageTitle: 'Events',
      path: '/events',
      hasProducts: events.length > 0
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

} else {
  console.log('User not authenticated');
  res.status(401).send('User not authenticated');
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines are the culprit.

```
req.session.save((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/');
          });
          return res.redirect('/events');
```

Here you pass a callback into `save` and immediately redirect  `res.redirect('/events')`.
After some time when callback redirect `res.redirect('/');` throws an error.